# Composer versioning (what does each number means?)

Tags: php, composer

I realy didn't find any answer on simple queastion what doues each number(example: 1.0.0) in version means? I can imagine that minor major ones, like if our packege became 1.0.1 so some minor changes happens. But, can someone describe it more wisely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first number is a whole extension version, for an example if you make a completely different version, let's say refactoring everything, and other huge changes such as db tables, etc, the first would be changed.

The second number is for new features in the same version. Let's say you are working on payment method under development version 0.0.1 and you just added the refund functionality. It should become 0.1.0

And the third one is for small changes, I'd usually consider bug fixes. You just added the refund functionality but you found a bug! Now it should become 0.1.1

Comment: As an addition - this scheme is known as "Semantic versioning" - Wikipedia also knows some stuff about it.